# iOS UIViewAnimation for uitableview cells

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, tableview, uiviewanimation

Currently I have a table view that if a cell is selected, the table is reloaded with a cell at the selected index path using the animation UITableTableViewRowAnimationFade. I don't like it very much as it is choppy and not smooth. I am not at all familiar with UIView animations and am looking to learn more about them. How would I animate this operation to be smoother and look nicer? Thanks.

Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath.row) {

        selectedCellIndexPath = -1;
        [callsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }

    if (selectedCellIndexPath >= 0)
    {
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedCellIndexPath inSection:0];
        selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.row;
        [callsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath.row;

    [callsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are your cells heavy (i.e. lots of content that needs to be calculated?).  You don't have any control over the particulars of a `UITableViewCell` animation other than the type.

Comment: visit http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewRowAnimation

Comment: They are not super heavy, but they are subclassed table cells if that matters...